# Unable to trigger Modal from button within table row in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, core-ui

I have two files: `Modal.js` and `Users.js`. Users.js contains a table that has an API get query mapped to it, in the final column of the table is a a dropdown for each row that contains three buttons; View, Edit and Delete. I would like the Delete button to trigger the Modal containing a message that roughly reads "Are you sure you wish to delete the user?".

I am struggling to get the Modal to trigger in the onClick event of the Delete component in the `Users.js` file, I'll attach the code for the two files below.

**Modal.js** (I have not edited any of the content in the modal yet)

```js
import {
  CButton,
  CModal,
  CModalHeader,
  CModalTitle,
  CModalBody,
  CModalFooter,
} from "@coreui/react";

const Modal = ({ visible, setVisible }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <CModal visible={visible} onClose={() => setVisible(false)}>
        <CModalHeader onClose={() => setVisible(false)}>
          <CModalTitle>Modal title</CModalTitle>
        </CModalHeader>
        <CModalBody>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</CModalBody>
        <CModalFooter>
          <CButton color="secondary" onClick={() => setVisible(false)}>
            Close
          </CButton>
          <CButton color="primary">Save changes</CButton>
        </CModalFooter>
      </CModal>
    </>
  );
};

export default Modal;
```

**Users.js**

```js
<CTableRow v-for="item in tableItems" key={rows.userID}>
  <CTableDataCell className="text-center">{rows.userID}</CTableDataCell>
  <CTableDataCell>{rows.firstName}</CTableDataCell>
  <CTableDataCell>
    <div>{rows.lastName}</div>
  </CTableDataCell>
  <CTableDataCell className="column-overflow">{rows.email}</CTableDataCell>
  <CTableDataCell>{rows.role}</CTableDataCell>
  <CTableDataCell>{rows.createdAt}</CTableDataCell>
  <CTableDataCell>{rows.updatedAt}</CTableDataCell>

  <CTableDataCell>
    <strong>{rows.lastLogin}</strong>
  </CTableDataCell>
  <CTableDataCell>
    <CDropdown>
      <CDropdownToggle color="transparent"></CDropdownToggle>
      <CDropdownMenu>
        <CDropdownItem className="dropdown-item pointer">View</CDropdownItem>
        <CDropdownItem className="dropdown-item pointer">Edit</CDropdownItem>

        <CDropdownItem
          className="dropdown-item text-danger pointer"
          onClick={() => Modal()} <- Issue here
        >
          Delete
        </CDropdownItem>
      </CDropdownMenu>
    </CDropdown>
  </CTableDataCell>
</CTableRow>;
```

I would appreciate any assistance with this. Let me know if I can give any other code (I have reduced the Users.js file as it is just over 160 lines long and I don't want to clutter, except for the row so you can get an idea of where the Delete button lives).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Modal` component needs to be in the page with a `visible` prop controlled by the parent (and not called as a function). The [CoreUI examples for `CModal`](https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/modal/#live-demo) are a bit misleading for your use-case.  I suggest using `useState` in your parent `Users` component and passing a setter callback to the `Modal` for the close event.

For example:

Users.js

```
const Users = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = React.useState(null);

  const rows = [
    { userID: "1", firstName: "Cameron", lastName: "E" },
    { userID: "2", firstName: "Steve", lastName: "G" }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <CTable>
        {rows.map((row) => {
          return (
            <CTableRow v-for="item in tableItems" key={row.userID}>
              <CTableDataCell className="text-center">
                {row.userID}
              </CTableDataCell>
              <CTableDataCell>{row.firstName}</CTableDataCell>
              <CTableDataCell>
                <div>{row.lastName}</div>
              </CTableDataCell>
              <CTableDataCell className="column-overflow">
                {row.email}
              </CTableDataCell>
              <CTableDataCell>{row.role}</CTableDataCell>
              <CTableDataCell>{row.createdAt}</CTableDataCell>
              <CTableDataCell>{row.updatedAt}</CTableDataCell>

              <CTableDataCell>
                <strong>{row.lastLogin}</strong>
              </CTableDataCell>
              <CTableDataCell>
                <CDropdown>
                  <CDropdownToggle color="transparent">
                    Dropdown button
                  </CDropdownToggle>
                  <CDropdownMenu>
                    <CDropdownItem className="dropdown-item pointer">
                      View
                    </CDropdownItem>
                    <CDropdownItem className="dropdown-item pointer">
                      Edit
                    </CDropdownItem>

                    <CDropdownItem
                      className="dropdown-item text-danger pointer"
                      onClick={() => {
                        setSelectedUser(row);
                        setVisible(true);
                      }}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </CDropdownItem>
                  </CDropdownMenu>
                </CDropdown>
              </CTableDataCell>
            </CTableRow>
          );
        })}
      </CTable>
      <Modal
        visible={visible}
        user={selectedUser}
        onClose={() => setVisible(false)}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Modal.js

```
const Modal = ({ visible, onClose, user }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <CModal visible={visible} onClose={onClose}>
        <CModalHeader onClose={onClose}>
          <CModalTitle>Delete {user.firstName}?</CModalTitle>
        </CModalHeader>
        <CModalBody>
          Are you sure you want to delete {user.firstName}? (He's a good guy.)
        </CModalBody>
        <CModalFooter>
          <CButton color="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
            Yeah he is a good guy
          </CButton>
          <CButton color="primary">Nuke 'Em!</CButton>
        </CModalFooter>
      </CModal>
    </>
  );
};
```

*Note:* As an added bonus, I added an example of passing the selected user to the `Modal` so only one instance of the `Modal` component exists in the page.

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-leftpad-l5ivqy?file=/src/Modal.js

Users.js Rendered
[image: Users.js Rendered]

Modal.js Rendered
[image: Modal.js Rendered]

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much, Mr Gomez! May I buy you a coffee haha? You've really helped me out of a bind here!

Comment: Thank you so much for adding the user prop as well. I think you could figure out where I was going with all of this haha!

Comment: @cameronErasmus Haha Yeah -- my code could use a little cleanup, but I wanted to give you a head start, if you needed it. Cheers!

Comment: Do you know how to implement CoreUI’s toast notifications? I have a use case for them in the same section of code above (I.e. when a user is successfully deleted). If you’re keen to take a swing at it I’ll create a new question for it. CoreUI’s docs are not very comprehensive, I’ve found

Comment: @cameronErasmus I had never even heard of CoreUI before I stumbled over your original question. ;) But I can give it a shot!